# How to handle maps in google maps app?

Tags: applications, google-account, google, google-maps

I am having some trouble with some easy stuff on Google Maps and was wondering if anyone could help.

I am running Google Maps on Android 4.4.2. When I click on the menu icon in the upper left and select a map the selected map becomes the current map and I can then see places saved to that map. However, on Android

1. How do I rename a map?
2. How do I get Google Maps to display a list of all places (which appear as yellow stars) which have been saved to that map?
3. What is the difference between a star on the map and a red circle with inverted red "drop"-shape on top?
4. When I click on the blue-on-white GPS icon, a map of my surroundings is displayed, with a blue circle with BLUE ARROW indicating my position. But what does the aforementioned bluearrow do (suppose I'm just pacing down the street and the sky is clear).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. If by rename you mean give it a proper name instead of the ugly co ordinates google maps shows its not possible currently. People have said that changing the name by going to the desktop version applies to the app also but it did not work for me.
2. Press the 3 parallel lines button and then press "My Places"
3. -
4. The arrow points towards the direction you are suppose to be travelling in. It shows only in the realtime navigation view. However sometimes it may point in the opposite direction (probably a compass error). But if you are moving it usually shows the correct direction.